# Recovery of failed RAID (RAID10)

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I have a hosted server that was configured for RAID10. I didn't perform the original configuration, so I'm trying to handle the scenario delicately. Based on my inspection, they setup x3 RAID10 arrays (md0, md1, md2) across 4 disks.

After initial boot, mdadm begins throwing errors and drops to the shell because of an unknown UUID. md0 and md1 seem fine, but md2 shows x2 disks were kicked (non-fresh) then fails to assemble.

I'm hoping I'll be able to add sdb5 back to the array and rebuild from there. sda5 shows low event count, while sdb5 shows identical event count to the x2 active disks (sdc5, sdd5).

They're currently provisioning an additional drive to use for recovery. Going to run ddrescue soon as it's ready. I have some ideas on how to proceed. I know I can run a forced assembly, but don't want to make any moves until I get a backup. I have some experience with software raid, primarily ZFS though. I wanted to get some insight from resident experts on what I'm looking at and the best path forward.

Details are below. Sorry about all the screens, but I'm working through IPMI KVM. Let me know if you need more info.

**dmesg:**

```
md: kicking non-fresh sda5 from array
md: kicking non-fresh sdb5 from array
...
md:raid10/md2: not enough operational mirrors
```

**cat /proc/mdstat:**

[image]

**mdadm -D /dev/md2:**

[image: mdadm -D /dev/md2 (a)]
[image: mdadm -D /dev/md2 (b)]

**mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sda5:**

[image: mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sda5]

**mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdb5:**

[image: mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdb5]

**mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdc5:**

[image: mdadm -misc --examine /dev/sdc5]

Answer (score 0):

I successfully repaired the drive via the following steps...

1. Used **ddrescue** to clone the (x4) disks to attached storage:

```
sudo ddrescue --verbose --idirect --no-scrape /dev/sda5 /mnt/backup/sda5.img /dev/backup/sdb5.logfile
```

2. Assembled the array with the clean members:

```
mdmadm -a --force /dev/md2 /dev/sd[bcd]5
```

3. Added member 0 back to the array and waited for rebuild to complete. All is well (and I'm currently migrating to a new provider).